# How to make glowing particles, with a solid glowing center

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, workflow

How can I create a material that looks like this?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you voting this question down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**3 Concentric Spheres with Emission Particles**

**Blur in Compositor**

[image]
Render result and 3 Concentric Spheres each with a particle system.  Image above.

Click on images to see larger view.

[image]

Compositor with Blur and Alpha Over Nodes. Image Above.

[image]
Particle Settings. 3 Panel of which 2 are pinned.  Unpinned is the largest sphere particle system.  Image above.

[image]

The 3 Object particles and the material settings. 2 are pinned.

Please experiment to your taste and improve.
Consider using a more irregular sphere in the center.
You may look at the movement of particle system on many frames and choose some particular frame.

Sloppy Imitation which may serve as a starting point.
Of course there are alternative and more CPU intensive ways to do this.

Comment: For complex effects like this, with many different settings, I would suggest uploading a blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to save having to have many images of settings.