# Tip for create shine effect

Tags: light, effects

i am beginner in blender. I started modelling hard surface (roulette with slot machine reel). Now I want to add light effect (like light spirals, jet fires, ...) in cycles. I dont know create this effect in 3D now. I know only add this effect in phosothop now. But I whant to know add it in 3D in the future :) And I would animate this effect in the future too. Can you help me the best way to create this effect in ming with future plans?

image from blender
[image]

added effects in photoshop
[image]

Comment: Do you mean glow effect?

Comment: Can these links help you?
Maybe this can help you create a spiral https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79436/how-do-you-make-a-spiral and add some glow to it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66905/creating-a-glowing-effect-with-nodes Making particles similar links: https://blenderartists.org/t/glowing-particles/453454/6 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50564/how-to-make-glowing-particles-with-a-solid-glowing-center

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several effects here. For the light rings effect, you can create a curve circle, give it depth in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Geometry > Beve*l, then give it a material with this node setup: *Texture Coordinate (Object* output) > *Mapping* (stretched on the correct axis) > *Noise Texture* (play with the *Scale* value) > *ColorRamp* as a factor in a *Mix Shader* between an *Emission* and a *Transparent* node. You can make it rotate with the *Mapping* rotation values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In cycles i had to add Glare to composition of output.

Comment: sure, and in Eevee don't forget to enable all the necessary settings for transparency (Alpha Blend and so on)