# How to make an airflow animation?

Tags: rendering

[image: Example]

Hi Artists,

Any idea how to do an airflow simulation motion "photo attached"?

I am not sure if this can be done on Blender or I should fake it in postprocessing using Affter effect or any other software :(  , I would really appreciate your ideas to help me with this, thanks.

Comment: Do you have an animation reference to show? From a still image we can only guess what the motion would look like.

Comment: maybe check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218562/tip-for-create-shine-effect/218576#218576

Comment: Thank you man, I really gonna use your answer for another part of the project, this is the reference video for the motion: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1oZ-KNEpE0

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi Carlo, Thank you again,

I used your previous answer with a line curve and I think it was what I looking for :), I have attached the reference video link so please review it and let me know if you have another technique you think it would be better otherwise this would be good enough.

All the best.